# Not understanding how Bootstrap's justify-content-between is working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with bootstrap's justify-content-between. I have 2 divs inside a container and I want to position them at the extreme ends of the container. So I am using justify-content-between, but it is evenly distributing the space between the 2 divs, which I don't want. I want no space at the start i.e. extreme left and end i.e. extreme right. If I know correctly then justify-content-between should accumulate the space in the middle and place the divs at the extreme end.

the code is:

```
<div class="container flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
    <div class="block col-md-6">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block col-md-5">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is looking like this now: (Notice the space marked by the violet region on the browser)
[image]

I am using Brave browser.
Kindly, please help me out. I don't know how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot `row` Class

Comment: As @LaljiTadhani commented, you need a row (Bootstrap likes a container, a row, and then the columns) and apply your `justify-content-between` to the row.

Comment: After adding an extra parent div as row and justify-content-between, still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here is the working example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex;" class="container-fluid flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
        <div class="block col-md-6">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block col-md-5">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `container` div and applying `justify-content-between` to the row pushes the two columns to the left and right, leaving a single-column space in the middle (it’s a single column space because your left column is 6 columns wide and your right columns is 5 columns wide).

Using a `container-fluid` div and applying `justify-content-between` to the row makes the row go full width and pushes the two columns to the left and right, leaving a single-column space in the middle.

I like using the `row` div in a Bootstrap layout inside the `container` div as that’s the way Bootstrap is setup to work.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-between bg-success">
        <div class="block col-md-6 bg-info pt-5">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block col-md-5 bg-info pt-5">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-between bg-success">
        <div class="block col-md-6 bg-info pt-5">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block col-md-5 bg-info pt-5">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your question used col-md-5 and col-md-6, so for smaller screens, the display goes to col-12. I used the same column sizing in my answer.

One note about using Stackoverflow – you added a comment on May 14 a little while after I posted my comment, but since you didn’t include @Rich, Stackoverflow didn’t let me know you had posted a comment. Only the original poster gets notified for all comments and posts – the rest of us are only included if you specifically include a reference to our name (or if the comment follows an answer that we posted).

Answer (score -1):

I have added 2 child divs in parent div and applied css and its working fine.

Try adding css style as below:

[image]

Regards,
Nisha Patel